# Failing to use VBOs in OpenGl/Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, vbo

Greetings my fellow programmers,

I've searched the WEB, checked examples online but still can't figure it out. I'm sorry if this was asked previously, I'm tired after a week-long debug of this. I hope you can help me.

Basically the problem is that I try to draw some quads (with triangles) but nothing is drawn. Previously I was drawing without VBOs the way described in 'Triangle example' on official Android website. Everything worked fine, but I decided that updating vertices/indices buffers in Renderer.OnDrawFrame() is not efficient :)

So here is my code:

```
public class FloorPlanRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

public volatile float mAngle;

// mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

private GLSurfaceView mGlView;
private GlEngine mGlEngine;
private boolean dataSet = false;

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Initialize the accumulated rotation matrix
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);

    // Position the eye in front of the origin.
    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = -3.0f;

    // We are looking toward the distance
    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = 0.0f; //-5.0f;

    // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    // Set the view matrix. This matrix can be said to represent the camera position.
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    mGlEngine = new GlEngine(10);
    mGlEngine.registerQuad(new Wall(-0.5f, 0.4f, -0.2f, 0.4f));
    mGlEngine.registerQuad(new Wall(0.5f, 0.4f, 0.2f, 0.4f));
    mGlEngine.registerQuad(new Wall(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.02f));
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 3.0f;
    final float far = 7.0f;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    float[] scratch = new float[16];

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

    // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    mGlEngine.render(scratch);
}
```

}

GlEngine class:

```
public class GlEngine {
public static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
public static final int ORDER_INDICES_PER_QUAD = 6;
public static final int VERTICES_PER_QUAD = 4;
public static final int SIZE_OF_FLOAT = Float.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;
public static final int SIZE_OF_SHORT = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

private int mQuadsNum = 0;
private int mLastCoordsIndex = 0;
private int mLastOrderIndex = 0;

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

// Use to access and set the view transformation
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

private final int mProgram;

private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;

private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f };
private boolean mDataInitNeeded = true;

public GlEngine(int quadsNum) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(quadsNum * VERTICES_PER_QUAD *
            COORDS_PER_VERTEX * SIZE_OF_FLOAT);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // device hardware's native byte order
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();

    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(quadsNum *
            ORDER_INDICES_PER_QUAD * SIZE_OF_SHORT);
    bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    indexBuffer = bb2.asShortBuffer();

    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public void registerQuad(Wall quad) {
    quad.putCoords(vertexBuffer);
    quad.putIndices(indexBuffer);
    mQuadsNum++;
}

// This code is dealing with VBO side of things
private final int[] mVerticesBufferId = new int[BUFFERS_COUNT];
private final int[] mIndicesBufferId = new int[BUFFERS_COUNT];
private static final int BUFFERS_COUNT = 1;

public void copyToGpu(FloatBuffer vertices) {
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(BUFFERS_COUNT, mVerticesBufferId, 0);

    // Copy vertices data into GPU memory
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticesBufferId[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.capacity() * SIZE_OF_FLOAT, vertices, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Cleanup buffer
    vertices.limit(0);
    vertices = null;
}

public void copyToGpu(ShortBuffer indices) {
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(BUFFERS_COUNT, mIndicesBufferId, 0);

    // Copy vertices data into GPU memory
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBufferId[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.capacity() * SIZE_OF_SHORT, indices, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Cleanup buffer
    indices.limit(0);
    indices = null;
}

public void render(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    setData();

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticesBufferId[0]);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, 0);

    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBufferId[0]);

    // Draw quads
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
            GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mQuadsNum * ORDER_INDICES_PER_QUAD,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// This method is called on gl thread GlSurfaceView.queueEvent(...)
public void setData() {
    if (mDataInitNeeded) {
        // Reset positions of buffers for consuming in GL
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        indexBuffer.position(0);

        copyToGpu(vertexBuffer);
        copyToGpu(indexBuffer);

        mDataInitNeeded = false;
    }
}

public void deallocateGlBuffers() {
    if (mVerticesBufferId[0] > 0) {
        GLES20.glDeleteBuffers(mVerticesBufferId.length, mVerticesBufferId, 0);
        mVerticesBufferId[0] = 0;
    }
    if (mIndicesBufferId[0] > 0) {
         GLES20.glDeleteBuffers(mIndicesBufferId.length, mIndicesBufferId, 0);
        mIndicesBufferId[0] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

The Wall class which represents rectangle:

```
public class Wall {
// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
private static final int VERTICES_NUM = 4; // it's a rect after all
private static final float DEFAULT_WIDTH = 0.05f;
private static final float DEFAULT_COORDS_SOURCE = 0.5f;

private final float mCoords[] = new float[COORDS_PER_VERTEX * VERTICES_NUM];

private final short mDrawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2,   // first triangle
                                     1, 2, 3 }; // second triangle

private int mVertexBufferPosition;
private int mIndexBufferPosition;

private final PointF mA = new PointF(0, 0);
private final PointF mB = new PointF(0, 0);
private float mWidth;

public Wall() {
    init(-DEFAULT_COORDS_SOURCE, DEFAULT_COORDS_SOURCE, DEFAULT_COORDS_SOURCE,
            -DEFAULT_COORDS_SOURCE, DEFAULT_WIDTH);
}

public Wall(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    init(x1, y1, x2, y2, DEFAULT_WIDTH);
}

public Wall(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float width) {
    init(x1, y1, x2, y2, width);
}

private void init(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float width) {
    mA.x = x1;
    mA.y = y1;
    mB.x = x2;
    mB.y = y2;
    mWidth = width;
    calcCoords();
}

private void calcCoords() {
    float[] vector = {mA.x - mB.x, mA.y - mB.y};
    float magnitude = (float) Math.sqrt(vector[0]*vector[0] + vector[1]*vector[1]);
    float[] identityVector = {vector[0]/magnitude, vector[1]/magnitude};
    float[] orthogonalIdentityVector = {identityVector[1], -identityVector[0]};

    mCoords[0] = mA.x + mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[0];
    mCoords[1] = mA.y + mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[1];

    mCoords[3] = mA.x - mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[0];
    mCoords[4] = mA.y - mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[1];

    mCoords[6] = mB.x + mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[0];
    mCoords[7] = mB.y + mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[1];

    mCoords[9] = mB.x - mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[0];
    mCoords[10] = mB.y - mWidth * orthogonalIdentityVector[1];
}

public void putCoords(FloatBuffer vertexBuffer) {
    mVertexBufferPosition = vertexBuffer.position();
    for (int i = 0; i < mDrawOrder.length; i++) {
        mDrawOrder[i] += mVertexBufferPosition/GlEngine.COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    }
    vertexBuffer.put(mCoords);
}

public void putIndices(ShortBuffer indexBuffer) {
    mIndexBufferPosition = indexBuffer.position();
    indexBuffer.put(mDrawOrder);
}

public float getWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public void setWidth(float mWidth) {
    this.mWidth = mWidth;
}

public PointF getA() {
    return mA;
}

public void setA(float x, float y) {
    this.mA.x = x;
    this.mA.y = y;
}

public PointF getB() {
    return mB;
}

public void setB(float x, float y) {
    this.mB.x = x;
    this.mB.y = y;
}
}
```

In Wall class I save offset where it places its vertices and indices because this class will be changing in the future and it intended to update its vertices in the main buffer (the buffer will not be recompiled for each OnDrawFrame).

Thank you. I hope with your help I will somehow overcome this (another) obstacle on my way to OpenGl ES.

Comment: I would try setting the "near" value a little smaller. Right now, your geometry is exactly on the near clip plane.

Comment: Could you please point me to exact line in the code?

Comment: `final float near = 3.0f;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me! I incidentally put indices into wrong array. Instead of this:

```
// Copy vertices data into GPU memory
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBufferId[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.capacity() * SIZE_OF_SHORT, indices, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

There should be:

```
// Copy vertices data into GPU memory
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBufferId[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.capacity() * SIZE_OF_SHORT, indices, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Why shame? because in the log I saw:

07-23 16:20:05.442 5170-5264/com.example.neutrino.maze W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Just after the second call to glBufferData where I put `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. This was for sure caused by copy-paste as in many cases.